# Finding the closed form of this recurrence

Tags: recurrence-relation, recursion

> We have the following recurrence $T$:
>   $$
> T(n,k) = \left\{
>         \begin{array}{ll}
>             \alpha n^2 + \beta n + \delta & \quad \text{if }\; n \le k \\
>             T(\lceil n / 2 \rceil, k) + T(\lfloor n / 2 \rfloor, k) + \gamma n + \zeta & \quad \text{if }\; n > k \\
>         \end{array}
>     \right.
> $$
>
> for all positive integers $n$ and $k$

I want to find a closed-form of $T$.

I at least know that when $n > k$, then

- If $n$ is even, then $T(n,k) \;=\; 2T(\frac{n}{2}) + \gamma n + \zeta$
- If $n$ is odd, then $T(n,k) \;=\; T((n-1)/2) + T((n+1)/2) + \gamma n + \zeta$

Usually I would enter a range of inputs $n$ to find a pattern. However, there are so many constants here, I cannot find a consistent pattern to get a closed-form.

Comment: Are you looking for an exact answer or would you be satisfied with asymptotics?

Comment: You can get rid of $\zeta$ by looking at $T(n,k) + \zeta$. Then you can get rid of $\gamma$ by simply dividing by $\gamma$. This should at least allow you to get a very good estimate for $n \gg k$.